# How to replace a string in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have  500+ program files  in a project. I would like to replace  a string "vector" to "std::vector" in all the files. How can I do this in Eclipse? I am using Eclipse CDT Helios.

(One option is to use Search->Search and enter the string to be replaced and press "Replace" button. But the problem here is that, it will replace  "vectorOfPoints" and "pointsVector" also.)

Comment: Why not use some classic Unix/POSIX commands such as `find`, `grep` and `sed` to do this?

Comment: I could do that too. But when I need to review the changes before saving, the IDEs do a better job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could just search for ' vector ' and replace it with ' std::vector ' as you described yourself. Instead make sure there is a space leading and ending your search, so you take only the single word vector.

Maybe you'll only need a space in the end, if vector occurs at the start of a new line. Also make sure your search is case sensitive.

Comment: Yes, this should solve the problem. I need to try with few options (without the quotes) like  " vector "  " vector" " vector<" (for items like vector<int>) Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

By using `Search` -> `File...` from the menu you can search for strings in any files. As `Containing text` you should use a regular expression so that `vectorOfPoints` will not match. Then click on `Replace...` and Eclipse will look up all occurrences. Here you can even have a preview before executing the replace operation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Edit->Find/Replace and from options select whole world so it will not replace vectorOfPoints